# Mocking Validates Uniqueness Callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rr

How do you mock out the `validates :name, uniqueness: true` callback for an attribute?

I imagine it would work something like this:

```
describe "with duplicate name" do
  before { mock(subject.name).unique? { false } }

  it "should be invalid" do
    subject.should have(1).error_on(:name)
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using [shoulda matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/)? With it you can test standard common rails functionality with one-liners like `it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name) }`. I find it more readable and eliminates the need for mocking callbacks and preparing test cases

Comment: Thanks Wei. Shoulda's definitely clean but I don't think I can justify ripping out the rest of my tests for this one spec!

Comment: What do you mean by ripping out the rest of your tests? like other validations and such tested through mocking?